# Splitting one bitcoin between two people

Tags: bitcoin

I am quite new to Bitcoins and have two questions.

Lets say person `A` owns 1 Bitcoin. `A` wants to send `.5` BTC to person `B` and `.5` BTC to person `C` in a single transaction. Is this possible to do within one single transaction ?

Later on if Person `C` sends the 0.5 Bitcoin it obtained from `A` to Person `B`, will it be possible for person `B` to verify that the Bitcoin which it now received from Person `B` and the one which it already received from Person `A`, were from the same source?

Comment: Why is this question voted down?

Comment: I'm guessing because it's a cross post. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43785/splitting-one-bitcoin-between-two-people/43786

Comment: @Jannes is that a problem? I wanted answer. And if multiple people could answer it would be great I suppose. Why down voting ?

Comment: @jgm I didn't do the downvote and I don't know the rules well enough to say if it is a problem or not (although in general on the internet cross posting the same thing to different (sub)forums is considered rude/spam). I guess mods here might decide to migrate this question to bitcoin.SE (since it seems off-topic here if I'm not mistaken). And then I guess it could be merged with the question over there.

Comment: @Jannes There was already a tag in Stackoverflow for the same. It means I can post in StackOverflow right ? And I am not the one who created the tag.

Comment: It is preferred that you only ask a question on the site where it is most applicable, or if you must ask a substantially similar question to different sites that you tailor them specifically to each site. [Please don't post exact duplicates of questions to multiple sites.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu?answertab=votes#tab-top) In this case, I think Bitcoin.SE is the better home for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sending a bitcoin value to multiple outputs/recipients in a single transaction is possible.

See here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction

And yes, person C will be able to verify that the two bitcoin values originated both from A, since the entire blockchain is publicly readable.